# OpenGL: Trying to create a solid cylinder using triangle_fan

Tags: opengl

I am trying to create a solid cylinder using triangle fan.
What I've done so far is this:

```
float base = 0.5;
float height = 20;
float radius = 2.0f;
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
for(float j=0; j<=height; j+=0.1)
{
    glVertex3f(0,j,0);
    for(int i=0; i<360; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(radius*sin((float)i),j, radius*cos((float)i));
    }   
}
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

The problem appears in these 3 screenshots:

[image]
As you see in all 3 screenshots there appears to be some space and not a solid cylinder.
Is that ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should pay attention to (**Edit:** I slightly misread your code. You are doing fine with the triangle fan) is that a triangle fan works like this:

```
glVertex: Center point
for each outer point p
    glVertex: p
```

For example:

```
                  p2__
                 /|   ---___p1
                /  |         /
               /    |       /
            p3/      |     /
              |\      |   /
              |   \    | /
               |     \_O   Center
               | __---
               p4
```

Second thing is that a cylinder consists of three parts:

```
               __
              /  \
              \__/        <---- circle on top (facing up)
              |  |
              |  |
              |  |
              |  |        <---- tube in the middle
              |  |
              |  |
              |  |
              \__/        <---- circle on the bottom (facing down)
```

So the algorithm you need is:

```
/* top triangle */
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex3f(0, height, 0);  /* center */
    for (i = 0; i <= 2 * PI; i += resolution)
        glVertex3f(radius * cos(i), height, radius * sin(i));
glEnd();

/* bottom triangle: note: for is in reverse order */
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);  /* center */
    for (i = 2 * PI; i >= 0; i -= resolution)
        glVertex3f(radius * cos(i), 0, radius * sin(i));
    /* close the loop back to 0 degrees */
    glVertex3f(radius, height, 0);
glEnd();

/* middle tube */
glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    for (i = 0; i <= 2 * PI; i += resolution)
    {
        glVertex3f(radius * cos(i), 0, radius * sin(i));
        glVertex3f(radius * cos(i), height, radius * sin(i));
    }
    /* close the loop back to zero degrees */
    glVertex3f(radius, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(radius, height, 0);
glEnd();
```

The way you were trying to do is first, not correct, since you are not actually making a cylinder, but stacking many circles, and second is inefficient since you are filling in space that is mostly invisible (the inside of the cylinder).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It now looks very good! I would like you to explain why is the 2nd for in reverse order?

Comment: In OpenGL, if you create a triangle by introducing points "A, B, C" or "A, C, B", you create the same triangle, but facing the other way. For example you may call [glCullFace](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCullFace.xml)(GL_BACK) to prevent OpenGL from drawing the triangles that are on the invisible side of the object. Back and front faces can also affect lighting. So, it is best to keep the order of the points so that the normal (use right-hand rule) would be facing outwards.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i<360; i++)
{
    glVertex3f
        (
        radius*sin((float)i),
        j, 
        radius*cos((float)i)
        );
}
```

The C standard library `sin()` and `cos()` functions take radians, not degrees.

Try converting `(float)i` to radians before you pass it to `sin()/cos()`.

Comment: That wouldn't be the problem. It is true, but he is doing many rounds, not less than one.

Comment: You could at least change it to `glVertex3fv`.

Comment: It worked just fine with degrees. Would it look better with radians?